# Python 3.6.1 OpenOPC install

Tags: python, python-3.x, opc, open-opc

Pardon me for my ignorance but I can't seem to get OpenOPC installed with Python 2.7 or 3.6.1. I found the github [code](https://github.com/ya-mouse/openopc) but it does not appear to include an installer. So I attempted to install the version for 2.7 from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openopc/). I can make the OpenOPC server talk using the instructions but after copying all the files from the python 3 project into my python directory I can import OpenOPC but when I try `opc = OpenOPC.client()` I get a fault.

> ```
> C:\>python
> Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import OpenOPC
> >>> opc = OpenOPC.client()
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> AttributeError: module 'OpenOPC' has no attribute 'client'
> >>>
> ```

Comment: I see this discussion on SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/p/openopc/discussion/709250/thread/bb4d19c9/?limit=25#a5b6

Comment: Honestly I would prefer to get this working in Python 3.x but it seems it might be easier to get it working on 2.7  instead. The problem on 2.7 is when I try to pip install anything it finds that in the Python 3.x installation and tells me it's already installed.                                             
The Python 2.7 error: 'NameError: global name 'pythoncom' is not defined'

Comment: I didn't venture too far in attempting this question because some of the libraries I use have no Py3.6 versions and the questions I've seen here on SO make Anaconda look like an unnecessary headache.

Comment: Try [this project](https://github.com/ya-mouse/openopc)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. I have installed OpenOPC through that [package](https://pypi.org/project/OpenOPC-Python3x/) thanks to pip:

```
pip install OpenOPC-Python3x
```

Hope it helps.